# CSS Select a child with parents that meet multiple conditions

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to select the element `<div name="inner">a-inner</div>` which is the child of the first `div` node.

To do so, I'm trying to create a selector which is a logical AND that the element has SOME parent with the defined property.

**I don't know what the parent hierarchy looks like beforehand, so I can't simply do:** `[role="foo"] > [letter=A] > [name=inner]`, because the hierarchy may not turn out that way.

```
<div role="foo">
 <div letter="A">
   <div name="inner">a-inner</div>
 </div>
 <div letter="B">
   <div name="inner">b-inner</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

In the Chrome console (using `$$` as shorthand for `document.querySelectorAll`, I first tried:
`$$('[role=foo]>[name=inner],[letter=A]>[name=inner]')` which returned the element

But then when I changed `foo` to`bar` as in `$$('[role=bar]>[name=inner],[letter=A]>[name=inner]')`, it still returned that same element.

I want the selector to select elements which have a parent with a list of properties.

**How do I format this?**

The order of which property comes first in the hierarchy is irrelevant, I just want to make sure that each selected element has some parent with the required property.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in pure CSS? It looks like you're using jQuery (or similar) for your selector?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to do this in pure CSS if possible, but if not possible then I don't mind if I need to whip out JS. And no, the `$$` is just shorthand in the Chrome console

Comment: Both your examples selected the same element because you are giving the system two ways of selecting (the two selectors either side of the comma are separate). So in your second example the system was finding the element through [letter-A]>[name=inner] not through the first selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the pseudo-selector [`first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type):

```css
div[role="foo"] > div:first-of-type > div[name="inner"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div role="foo">
 <div letter="A">
   <div name="inner">a-inner</div>
 </div>
 <div letter="B">
   <div name="inner">b-inner</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Or select based on the `letter` [attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```css
div[role="foo"] > div[letter="A"] > div[name="inner"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div role="foo">
 <div letter="A">
   <div name="inner">a-inner</div>
 </div>
 <div letter="B">
   <div name="inner">b-inner</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified, I can't use order to specify the selectors because all I know is that the element should have SOME parent with the matched property, but I don't know what the parent hierarchy will looklike beforehand.